# The building blocks of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, soft-question

In an introductory class to analysis, a theorem we prove is the characterization of intervals (I'm sure there is more than one by this name, but its not important for this question) but we don't prove anything about the "importance" of intervals in the context of $\mathbb{R}$. Something seems rather fundamental about them, and I am trying to pinpoint what it is. My first intuition was to prove that every subset of the real numbers can be written as a union of intervals, but this is trivially true since a single point can be considered a closed interval with the same upper and lower bounds.

My next idea was to think in terms of Topology, and prove something along the lines of "every subset of real numbers can be written as a union of non-trivial intervals and isolated points", this I think is more along the lines of what I wanted to capture, but then I thought of a description that act as an even stronger condition:

Define the *coarser* pre-order on families of sets of real numbers, formally let

$$\preceq \subseteq P(P(\mathbb{R}))^2 $$

Satisfying

$$\mathcal{A}\preceq \mathcal{B} \iff \\
\forall_{S\in \mathcal{A}}\exists_{S'\in \mathcal{B}}[S\subseteq S']  \land \\ \bigcup A = \bigcup B 
$$

Specifically if the sets in the families in question are disjoint, then when $\mathcal{A}\preceq \mathcal{B}$ we say that $\mathcal{B}$ is *coarser* that $\mathcal{A}$ (on a restriction to families with disjoint sets, the pre-order also becomes a partitial order)

This pre-order order allows us to then say something which is stronger than simply the isolated point-interval condition, which is that for every $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ there is some family of intervals, $\mathcal{K}$ such that $\mathcal{K}$ is a disjoint cover of $S$, and $\mathcal{K}$ is the maximal disjoint cover with respect to $\preceq$

To illustrate why I think this condition is stronger (in a general context) than the isolated-point interval condition, I remark that the isolated point interval condition holds even if you consider only closed sets, since an open set can be written as a union of non-trivial closed sets, but with the maximal condition relating to $\preceq$, closed sets are not enough to guarantee a maximum.

My questions then are:
Is this an interesting or useful way to characterise the role that intervals play in $\mathbb{R}$? Is there an analogous concept to the one described above, both in $\mathbb{R}$ and in general topological spaces (or some other generalisation of $\mathbb{R}$) ?

And lastly how would one go about proving the theorem of a maximal element? (I would include an attempt here, but my question is getting quite long)

Comment: "Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as union of intervals and isolated points" This is not true as Cantor set can't be written in such a way

Comment: intervals get a lot more important when you introduce the Borel sets, that, said in very simple term, is every real subset that has any hope of sanity. You can prove that you can always approximate them from the inside and from the outside with non-trivial intervals

Comment: @Jakobian,  I had no idea, this seemed like a very obvious statement, I would then not be surprised if my proposition about the maximal family also turns out to be false, but we shall see

Comment: Also, I would assume that your families of subsets are actually families of intervals, otherwise the maximal is always $\{S\}$

Comment: @Exodd, yes this is what I meant, will edit now

Comment: Can you give an example of a result that is important? In introductory analysis, it is assumed that we don't already know what a topology is or even a rigorous definition of continuity. Intervals are classified as closed and open because these form the basis of closed and open sets in general. Is it possible that you have read the punchline of a joke before hearing the joke and now wonder why it is supposed to be funny?

Comment: @JohnDouma I took a topology course before my real analysis course, which may be what you are referring to. I consider the classification theorem for intervals as important, because it strengthens our intuition about the types of sets that are intervals, but I don't think I (or anyone else) can give a general criterion for the importance of a result

Comment: @Carlyle That could explain the confusion. The concepts we learn in topology are abstractions of the concepts we learn in real analysis. I love Munkres' book  "Topology: A first course" but my main criticism of that book is that he defines an abstract topology with no connection to analysis. I believe that is pedagogically backwards.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to prove that a maximal element always exists by Zorn's lemma, and with few additional reasoning, you can also prove that it is unique, so actually we always have a maximum, and it is represented by the collection of the connected components of $S$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I have not really looked at Zorn's lemma before so I would appreciate if you could elaborate a bit on the statement, I am however aware that Zorn's lemma relies on AC, and if this theorem were true, I would not expect it to require AC, not sure if this is the case

Comment: You don't need Zorn's lemma since $\mathcal{K}$ can be explicitly stated as the collection of all components of $S$. This is nothing more than doing so. For example, the Cantor set would be written in terms of one-point sets